# Реализовать карусель

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, slick.js

Необходимо реализовать карусель подобным образом. Может у кого-то есть уже готовый пример.
Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.